# Make Tinymce listbox work with mobile devices

Tags: javascript, user-interface, ipad, mobile, tinymce

I am using a standard tinymce ui listbox (basically a button with a dropdown) with a few options.
I would like to make it work on mobile devices. But i do not seem to be able to achieve this.

I can access the control element of the listbox, but i am not able to find the dom elements that hold the options using the control element. If i would be able to get to them i could bind a touchstart handler and trigger the necessary function.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem or has a workaround?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found out it seems to work out of the box, but what i am trying to do onselect causes a problem.

Here is working a [tinymce fiddle example](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/CBfaab/1) just in case someone needs help.